# Retrieve the frame of UITableViewCell with margin

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to create a editable UITableViewCell, it works but I'm missing a margin:

[image]

Text are aligned directly to the left, no margin. So I guess the `cell.frame` part was a little bit wrong.

But I don't know what else to use, I tried `cell.contentView.frame`, nothing works:

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];

textField.placeholder     = @"What's your email address?";
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
textField.textAlignment   = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

[cell.contentView addSubview: textField];

return cell;
```

P.S I might add an icon later, I can't use static **margin** either, it must be calculated somehow

Comment: Do you create the cell programmatically? If not, you could add a textField in the storyboard, then add constraints and access it later with view tags?

Comment: @Aseider yeah, it is programatically added

Comment: Have you tried to add constraints programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

this should show you how to achieve that in a quick and dirty manner.  just drop this in place of your existing same named method to see whats going on then refactor it

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"myCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

        textField.placeholder     = @"What's your email address?";
        textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
        textField.textAlignment   = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        textField.text = @"hi";

        if ([textField respondsToSelector:@selector(setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:)]) {
            [textField setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: NO];
        }

        [cell.contentView addSubview: textField];

        NSDictionary * viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(textField);

        [cell addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[textField]-10-|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];

        [cell addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(>=1)-[textField(==20)]-(>=1)-|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];

        [cell addConstraint:
         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:textField
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                     toItem:cell
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                 multiplier:1
                                   constant:0]];

        textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    }

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: It's always cool to include a description of what's going on instead of just code, that makes it easier to understand :)

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate margin for textField:

```
CGFloat hPadding = 10.0;
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(hPadding, 0.0, 
                          NSWidth(cell.frame) - hPadding * 2.0, NSHeight(cell.frame))

UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

Comment: Where did you get that "hPadding" part ..? Is that value working with all iOS devices?

Comment: It's just a variable defined so you can easily change padding value, if you prefer you can use i.e: CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, NSWidth(cell.frame) - 10.0 * 2.0, NSHeight(cell.frame)) for padding of 10.0